# Google Maps API does not work properly on domain alias

Tags: api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a simple Google maps app that shows user-created places on it. I run the website on 2 domains using alias. On the new domain the map does not show the red pointers (representing the places/events).

Here is src code I use:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=...&sensor=true&libraries=places,geometry"></script>
```

Could you please point me towards a solution? Kindly thank you in advance.

Comment: Probably when you are creating the key you need to add the second domain also.

Comment: Thank you @xmux - I generated new API key with both URLs as Referers, but nothing changed.

Comment: Are you sure that you are using the same code for each domains. Maybe you can post it on jsfiddle.

Comment: I do - there is physically only 1 website hosted.

Comment: I found the solution - there was an exact URL path that loaded the XML data. I corrected it to a relative path and now the application works on both domains: "downloadUrl("mapa/map_data/data.xml?" + getRandomArbitrary(1000,9999), function(data)"

Comment: Ok so right your answer and check it or you can delete this question, so the other people wont loose time to check on that!

Comment: Thank you xmux, I would love to do that, but I see only upvote buttons and a star next to my question. Where is it possible to close the topic?

Comment: You can write your answer down below and check it! Thats it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution - there was an exact URL path that loaded the XML data. I corrected it to a relative path and now the application works on both domains: "downloadUrl("mapa/map_data/data.xml?" + getRandomArbitrary(1000,9999), function(data)"